# Count the accumulated hours within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have a table which holds information on the type of work a worker does and the amount of hours spent on the work.

eg.

```
work_id | user_id | work_type | hours_spent
-------------------------------------------------   
    1   |     1   |  Maintain |     7
    2   |     1   |  sick     |     4  
    3   |     1   |  maintain |     3
    4   |     1   |  maintain |     6
    5   |     2   |  Web      |     5
    6   |     2   |  Develop  |     8
    7   |     2   |  develop  |     5
    8   |     3   |  maintain |     5
    9   |     3   |  sick     |     7
    10  |     3   |  sick     |     7
```

I would like to count the amount of accumulated hours each user has spent on a type of work to display something like this:

```
user id | work_type | hours_spent
-----------------------------------
    1   |  maintain |     16 
    1   |  sick     |      4
    2   |  Web      |      5
    2   |  develop  |     13
    3   |  maintain |      5
    3   |  sick     |     14
```

The sum() function I'm using now returns all the hours in the hours_spent column. Is this the right function for what I want to achieve?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you show the query you're using right now that doesn't seem to give you the results you want?

Comment: I would rather not since it's very embarrassing for me. I over complicated things by having a sub query to find the sum hours..

Comment: meh, we were all beginners once. Showing your work helps us better identify where you went wrong, and can help you learn faster.

Comment: I've used a formula within access to find the percentage of time each individual has spent on a work type, Is there a way of getting the total sum of how much time every user has spent on a work_type?

Comment: Nevermind, seems like I've been able to do this within SQL by using sub queries for each work type. The results print with every record, but it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  work_type = LOWER(work_type), 
  hours_spent = SUM(hours_spent)
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY user_id, LOWER(work_type)
ORDER BY user_id, LOWER(work_type);
```

- You don't need `LOWER()` there unless you have a case sensitive collation. And if you do, enter those strings consistently - or better yet, use a lookup table for those strings and store a tinyint in the main table instead.

Comment: I would guess that the OP did not even notice the difference in case between the data and the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff probably true, but I wanted to make sure I mentioned it.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Now I just need to add the minutes (not mentioned) to the hours, but that I can do myself. And yeah my mistake, should have made it all lower case